# How to convert a particular date into timestamp?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a particular date (say 31st October 2017) to the timestamp.

What should be my input and how to convert it into timestamp?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you even google that question first?

Comment: @TheRickest `new Date("31st October 2017")` --> `Invalid Date`, the thread you point at is about dates formats like `31-10-2017`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `getTime` with `new Date(date_to_parse)`

```js
var example="31 October, 2017";
alert(new Date(example).getTime());
```

Comment: This is entirely dependent on browser behaviour - some may parse that format, some not - per the spec they aren't guaranteed to understand it.

Comment: Works with "31 October, 2017", not with OP's "31st October 2017" --> NaN

Comment: yeah, I think best way around that is to just get rid of the "st" by doing `.replace('st','')` or something along those lines.